# Storing an Image/File, passed as Base64 encoded String in request,to GAE datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

I am creating the server backend of my Android application in Google App Engine/java. there is a functionality of adding a profile picture.
From Android App,i am passing this image as Base64 encoded stream to my App Engine Servlet. I am confused as to how can i store this image(file) using blobstore api .Then i would create IMageURL of this blob using ImageService API.

Can anyone suggest a best way ,on how to ad

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1) [Decode the Base64 string on App Engine.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506428/convert-base64-string-to-image-in-java) Alternatively, just [POST the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935946/sending-images-using-http-post) itself without encoding it.

2) Store the image on [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted). Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318989/how-to-properly-upload-image-file-to-google-cloud-storage-using-java-app-engin).

3) Retrieve the image from Cloud Storage using the [getServingUrl](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/ImagesService#getServingUrl(com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobKey,%20int,%20boolean)) function from the [Blobstore API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage).

If you are doing image manipulations before serving, you can use the [Images API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/).